# Django вывод по выборке

Tags: python, django, выборка

Как вывести информацию на сайт по выборке?
Например, сайт отображающий инфу о 5 последних заехавших на парковку.
таблица:
дата-время | номер машины | позиция на парковке

Вопрос: как показать на сайте последние 5 заехавших встроенными в джанго средствами?

Можно отвечать ссылками на требуемую док-цию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В представлении сформируйте запрос с усечением данных и передайте в шаблон, после чего в шаблоне выводите данные этой выборки.

Например:

```
# models.py
class Parking(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    car_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    parking_position = models.CharField(max_length = 5)

# views.py
def cars_on_parking(request):
    cars = Parking.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
....
....

order_by('-timestamp') - сортировка по полю timestamp. в обратном порядке
[:5] - усечение данных в запросе, т.е. взять 5 записей из запроса.
```

После чего в переменной cars будет информация о 5 последних записях из модели Parking

Вы так же можете воспользоваться reverse() для запроса вместо order_by('-timestamp')

Прочитать можете про reverse() последующей ссылке:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#reverse

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что нужно, просто не знал как сделать